# QT5 How to access object in ui designer?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have create a ui designer object called `workspace` and there is a object named `myForm` promoted to my custom class named `CustomForm`.
And now I want access the object `myForm` in other class but I fail. In Workspace member function definition, I access myForm through `ui->myForm`, how can I acccess in other class?

Comment: Please be specific and show some minimal example. I just can guess what your problem is. If you want to access your Form from outside your ui-based class you have to keep in mind that the ui is private by default. Accessing ui-elements directly from outside the ui-based class is trivial by e.g. writing accessor functions but is (generally speaking) a really bad idea (design-wise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access it directly as `ui` is generally private.

But you can add a getter function (`CustomForm *myForm()`) that returns `ui->myForm` to your Workspace class.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me

Comment: OnWhenReady's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585269/qt5-how-to-access-object-in-ui-designer/37585912?noredirect=1#comment62657202_37585912) is also good to keep in mind as you generally don't want to expose child widgets. Requiring a direct access on a child widget can be a sign of a flaw in your software design.